# Deceleration of an aircraft while braking.

Tags: convergence-acceleration

I'm trying to determine the distance an aircraft traveled during a period of brake application using the following information:

Initial speed (v0) = 92 nautical miles per hour,
Final speed (v1) = 67 nautical miles per hour,
Initial time (t0) = 0,
Total braking duration (t1) = 5 seconds,
1 NM = 6067.12 Ft,

So I get that the aircraft slows at 25 nautical miles per hour in 5 seconds, but how do I get to how far in feet it traveled in that slice of time?

Comment: i don't think there is enough information to determine the distance traveled from the time the brake was applied to the time it came to a stop. one would need to know the way the velocity is changing, i.e. the deceleration as a function of $v$ or $t.$

Answer (score 0):

I will assume constant acceleration $a = - 5$ NM per hour per second.

first convert $v_0$ into units of feet per second and $a$ into units of feet per second squared.

then you can get the distance travelled from the formula ...

$$d = v_0 t + \frac 12 a t^2 $$

don't forget that $v_0 > 0 $ and $a <0$ and $t=5$s

Comment: From InvertedPlane, who presumably lost their login-credentials and couldn't post a comment, since they aren't considered the OP in this account: "Okay, and thanks! It's been a long time since I did multi-layer conversions, like 5NM/hr/sec to feet/sec/sec... quick lesson? Also, that does it... I'm grabbing some math books and diving back in. I've let too much slip away!!"